# How do I fix a broken scaffolding flip lock?

Tags: repair, safety, metal, masonry, welding

I have 5'x5' steel scaffolding and two of the flip locks are broken. On one of them, the stub and pin are intact with just the flip part gone, and the other one has the end of the stub broken off.  Is there a way to fix these without welding on new flip locks?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They might be threaded on.  Usually the rod itself will be welded on or they will weld on an attachment point.  Those look like attachment points welded on to the vertical pipes.  The broken one in the bottom picture will need replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look welded on. On Safway style scaffolding the drop locks are typically welded in place rather than threaded. If these are welded, replacements will need to be welded on as well. Since they are probably galvanized, doing the welding work will require a bit of prep to avoid 'fume fever', and the scaffolding will be more subject to rusting after the work since the galvanization will be removed and damaged by the welding.

However there's a slight chance they are threaded. It wouldn't hurt to try and loosen one before you go through the work of replacing them. You have the very best reference in front of you: the actual object. Your evaluation of it will provide more information than we ever can.

Meanwhile this scaffolding is not safe to use, as it is damaged. On the slight chance someone is foolish enough to use it, they should make certain there's some other locking mechanism in place such as a rope tied around the upright and cross bar.